# Constraint is not equal to the height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I write this following code :

```
if !self.headerIsCollapsed{
     self.headerIsCollapsed = true
     self.heightProfilView.constant -= (self.view.bounds.height / 5)
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
          self.imageUserProfil.layer.opacity = 0
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     })
     print(self.heightProfilView.constant)
     print(self.topUserProfilView.bounds.height)
}
```

My question is: Why the value of the two print() is not the same ?

I need the value of `self.topUserProfilView.bounds.height` Before animate this for another function, would there be another way to catch this value before?

thanks

Comment: self.heightProfilView --> For which view?

Comment: @RakeshPatel thanks for your reply. `self.heightProfilView` is a subview of `self.view` who have a height of 33% of `self.view`

Comment: i think 'self.heightProfilView' is a constraint. right? i mean this constraint is for which view?

Comment: @RakeshPatel Yes is a constraint of topUserProfilView

Comment: Now do you want updated value of topUserProfilView OR before update a constrint?

Comment: before, because I need to fix the height of another subview in the topUserProfilView

Comment: What I need is the value of the height of topUserProfilView after animate this one because i need to fix the height of another subview in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` function

Comment: I add an answer it will work

Comment: @RakeshPatel i rewrite the question here, if you can check please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186287/calcul-height-of-uiview-after-animating-this-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: it should work

```
if !self.headerIsCollapsed{
    self.headerIsCollapsed = true
    self.heightProfilView.constant -= (self.view.bounds.height / 5)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.imageUserProfil.layer.opacity = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (isCompleted) in
        print(self.heightProfilView.constant)
        print(self.topUserProfilView.bounds.height)
    }
    }
```

P.S: This solution would not work if you added the heightProfilView constraint relative to the any view height as here you are changing the constant but in the IB you have assigned the multiplier so in that case the default constant value is 0. So, this approach will not work for the relative height constraint. as we can't change the multiplier of a constraint.

Comment: thank for your reply, i test this solution but dont work ... i have again https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/27/4/1530774817-capture-d-ecran-2018-07-05-a-09-08-44.png

Comment: then something is wrong with height constraint . is it relative?

Comment: Please check . i have mentioned the reason of your issue in my answer. i hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank for your reply again, the height constraint depend of the view, In the storyboard i write the multiplier 0.33 depending of the uiview

Comment: this is the constraint: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/27/4/1530777397-capture-d-ecran-2018-07-05-a-09-56-00.png

Comment: yes, and what are you checking with topUserProfilView.bounds.height is wrong, You are expecting heightProfilView.constant value equal to topUserProfilView.bounds.height. which is wrong.

Comment: You know how can I catch the value after animating this ?

Comment: the value of topUserProfilView.bounds.height is always right. use this value.

Comment: Thanks, i rewrite my problem in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186287/calcul-height-of-uiview-after-animating-this-one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have constraints taking priority. Check out your console output when you collapse the row, there should be some loud output involving constraints.

Also try hiding `imageUserProfil`

```
self.imageUserProfil.layer.opacity = 0
self.imageUserProfil.isHidden = true
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. So, I try to add `self.imageUserProfil.isHidden = true` but not solve the problem and for the constraint I have not other constraints on this view for the height ...

Comment: @Daphyduck try adding `self.imageUserProfile.setNeedsUpdatwConstraints()` instead

Comment: not working but you think is the image who caused the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need completion block to do it...Just replace your animation method as below

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.imageUserProfil.layer.opacity = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (isDone) in
        print(self.heightProfilView.constant)
        print(self.topUserProfilView.bounds.height)
    }
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: thank but I try this and show again the same value : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/27/4/1530774817-capture-d-ecran-2018-07-05-a-09-08-44.png

Comment: Obvious it will be same because you give a height constraint to this view and update it then updated value always same.

Comment: What you need??

Comment: The first print() give me a negative value, this is normal ?

Comment: yes...it is because of your first and seconditem..but dont worry it is normal.

Comment: self.heightProfilView.constant -= (self.view.bounds.height / 5) --> remove minus sign

Comment: When i remove this, I have a crazy animation, i explain you the problem again in another world because I think a take the problem in a bad way for that I begin a new Question and I give you the link