# Calcul height of uiview after animating this one

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have an animation who modify the constraint of an UIView and i need to know the size of this UIView after animate this, but before the animation begin...

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kGST.png)

When the user scroll the UITableView I update the heightConstraint of the black UIView, I need the height after update the UIView because i need in the function `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to fixe the height of the Yellow UIview.

this is the code I use for animate the UIView:

```
self.headerIsCollapsed = true
self.heightProfilView.constant -= (self.view.bounds.height / 5)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   self.imageUserProfil.layer.opacity = 0
})
```

and i need the value here :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    heightTopBar.constant = // here i need the height of the UIView after animating this
}
```

So, the question is: How I can pre-calculate the height of the UIView after animating this ?

Comment: autolayout will automatically stretch the yellow view after the profile view height decreases , so remove the yellow height and it'll stretch automatically

Comment: What do you mean pre-calculate after animating ? It doesn't make sense. Maybe you meant before ?

Comment: Yes thank you, before. I learn about constraint and I anderstand better how it's work. My problem is solve

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a completion block of `UIView.animate()`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.imageUserProfil.layer.opacity = 0
}) { (finished) in
    // get the view's height after animation here
}
```

Unless you specified duration as 0, the completion block will execute after animation sequence ends.

Comment: Thanks but I need this value before the code animate, because i need to init in `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() `

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.headerIsCollapsed = true
//create this property at instance level in your viewcontroller class
self.heightBeforeAnimation = self.heightProfileView.frame.size.height
self.heightProfilView.constant -= (self.view.bounds.height / 5)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  self.imageUserProfil.layer.opacity = 0
}){ (isCompleted) in
    //create this property at instance level in your viewcontroller class
   self.heightAfterAnimation = self.heightProfileView.frame.size.height
}
```

and call whatever function and use the value of two variables containing value of height before and after animating your view.

Comment: OK thank this clear my mind! But it's possible to know the `self.heightAfterAnimation` before this code running, because i need to fix the height of an element when the viewDidLoad ?

Comment: do this self.heightBeforeAnimation = self.heightProfileView.frame.size.height as a first statement in viewDidLoad and i hope this is what you wanted. But for your information never do this kind of thing in viewDidLoad as during this call the view is loading so all of the views getting there dimensions and if try to get any view related property at that time you will probably get the intermediate value. But if you want this then do self.heightBeforeAnimation = self.heightProfileView.frame.size.height in viewDidLoad